# How to resolve NODE.Js HTTP POST "ECONNRESET" Error

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, http

I have this function and the below data which is passed into this function returns a ECONNRESET, socket hang up error. However, when the discountCode array is reduced to like only 10 objects, it can POST without any problem.

What could the cause for this problem? I tried to do multiple req.write() by segmenting the data in Buffer, however that doesn't work out well. Any NodeJs ninja could give some insights to this problem?

```
createObj: function(data, address, port, callback) {

//console.log('Create Reward: '+JSON.stringify(data));
var post_data = JSON.stringify(data);

var pathName = '/me/api/v1/yyy/'+data.idBusinessClient+'/newObj';

    // 
    var options = {
        hostname: address,
        port: port,
        path: pathName,
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip,deflate,sdch',
            'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.8'
        }
    };

    // http call to REST API server
    var req = restHttp.request(options, function(res) {

        console.log('HTTP API server PUT Reward response received.');
        var resData = '';
        res.on('data', function(replyData) {

            // Check reply data for error.
            console.log(replyData.toString('utf8'));
            if(replyData !== 'undefined')
                resData += replyData;
        });

        res.on('end', function() {
            //<TODO>Process the data</TODO>             
            callback(JSON.parse(resData));
        });
    });

    req.write(post_data);
    req.end();

    console.log('write end');

    req.on('close', function() {
        console.log('connection closed!');
    });

    req.on('error', function(err) {
        console.log('http request error : '+err);
        callback({'error':err});
        throw err;
    });

    req.on('socket', function(socket) {
        console.log('socket size:'+socket.bufferSize);
        socket.on('data', function(data) {
            console.log('socket data:'+data);
        });
    });

}
```

]}`

Comment: ECONNRESET means that the server closed the connection for some reason. Maybe it does not accept that amount of data? Is it an own written server API or something where a documentation is available?

Comment: Yes it's a own written server api with Java Spring framework. Still looking for the reason why it reject the data. Do you have any idea you could think of? ;)

Comment: can you add an Agent: Mozilla and Connection: Keep-Alive to the headers?

Answer (score 9):

I had the same problem and was able to resolve it by adding a Content-Length header:

```
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        'Content-Length': Buffer.byteLength(post_data),
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip,deflate,sdch',
        'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.8'
    }
```

However, I still have no clear idea why a missing Content-Length header causes such a trouble. I assume it's some kind of weirdness in the internal Node.js code. Maybe you can even call it a bug, but I'm not sure about that ;)

PS: I'm absolutely interested more information about the cause of this problem. So please leave a comment if you have any idea...

Comment: This error occurs when I'm testing with a leopard mac. However, when I tested it with a newer machine, there is no such problems anymore for me. And it doesn't show up on my target machine. So I'm also bewildered as you are :o

Comment: I had the same problem. I tried your solution and it works! I don't know why and if you have any idea, tell me please. Thanks.

Comment: Mine had to do with the port in the request.  Tried 443 for SSL but it didn't like it.

Answer (score 1):

When you change the content of response for sure you need also to update on header the content length:

```
headers: {
    ...
    'Content-Length': Buffer.byteLength(post_data),
    ...
}
```

But i run on this problem also when i try to make multiple request and seems that this is not well managed on different library so a workaround that i have found if this problem persist is to add on headers:

```
headers: {
    ...
    connection: 'Close'
    ...
}
```

So if you are making request on different servers.. this close the connection after finish the process. This worked for me in net, node-http-proxy.

Answer (score 1):

If [Express](https://expressjs.com) and [http-proxy-middleware](https://github.com/chimurai/http-proxy-middleware) is used to make the POST call, and some body parser middleware is used like [`express.json()`](http://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/body-parser.html#bodyparserjsonoptions), the request interceptor `fixRequestBody` must be used ([more info](https://github.com/chimurai/http-proxy-middleware#intercept-and-manipulate-requests)). Otherwise the POST call will hang with the `ECONNRESET` error.

```js
const express = require('express');
const { createProxyMiddleware, fixRequestBody } = require('http-proxy-middleware');

const app = express();
app.use(express.json());
app.post(
  '/path',
  createProxyMiddleware('/path', {
    target: API_URL,
    changeOrigin: true,
    pathRewrite: (path, req) => `/something/${req?.body?.someParameter}`,
    onProxyReq: fixRequestBody // <- Add this line
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem. The solution for me was to append it to the proxy for it to work. If you're not using a proxy, you can probably just append it to the post request itself.

With proxy:

```
import express from 'express';
import { createProxyMiddleware } from 'http-proxy-middleware';
import logger from './logger';

        // setup routes
        server.get('/isAlive', (req, res) => res.send('Alive'));
        server.get('/isReady', (req, res) => res.send('Ready'));

        server.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../build')));

        const restream = (proxyReq, req, res, options) => {
            if (req.body) {
                let bodyData = JSON.stringify(req.body);
                proxyReq.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
                proxyReq.setHeader('Content-Length', Buffer.byteLength(bodyData));
                proxyReq.write(bodyData);
            }
        };

        server.use(
            '/api',
            createProxyMiddleware({
                target: 'http://your-backendUrl-api',
                onProxyReq: restream,
                changeOrigin: true,
                proxyTimeout: 30000,
                secure: true,
                logLevel: 'info',
                onError: (err, req, res) => {
                    logger.error('error in proxy', err, req, res);
                },
            })
        );
```

E.g without proxy:

```
import axios, { AxiosResponse } from 'axios';

const api = axios.create({
    baseURL: '/api/....',
    timeout: 35000,
    withCredentials: true,
    headers: { Pragma: 'no-cache', 'Cache-Control': 'no-cache' },
    validateStatus: (status) => status < 400,
});

    const response = await api.post(
        `/somepath/${exampleInjectedId}/somepathToRestAPI`,
        {
         ...payload
        },
        {
            baseURL: '/api/...',
            timeout: 35000,
            withCredentials: true,
            headers: {
                Pragma: 'no-cache',
                'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
                'Content-Length': Buffer.byteLength(
                    JSON.stringify({
                        ...payload
                    })
                ),
            },
            validateStatus: (status) => status < 400,
        }
    );
```